# xhr xmlhttprequest won't work in browser?

Tags: javascript, browser

I am using a browser to send `XMLHttpRequest` to read a file on the server:

```
//Read Text File
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET","http://...........read.txt",false);
xhr.send(null); 
var fileContent = xhr.responseText;
```

But I got

> unknown error
>
> network error

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What network error are you getting? Can you include the wording of the error?

Comment: 1. Can you get the text file in a regular request (paste `http://...........read.txt` in your browser and see if you get an error). 2. Check the network tab in your developer tools, what *exactly* do you see for `http://...........read.txt`? 3. Are you making this request from the same domain, or trying to send the request to a different domain?

Comment: Why you sending null is send method

Comment: @AmitGolhar That shouldn't cause any issues. See [`xhr.send` spec](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-send()-method)

Comment: can you post your error please

Comment: on network tab I see status: 200 / method: get / cause: xhr / type: plain / transferred: cached, size 11b

Comment: this is a game, when I run on desktop app, its fine, but when run on index.html in a browser, it says a network error occurred. Maybe a similar equivalent code can solve this browser error?

Comment: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user’s experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/ rpg_objects.js line 10500 > eval:8:2
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://.......read.txt. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Comment: var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",false);
xhr.send(); 
console.log(xhr.responseText);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check with  status code condition like this:

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET","http://...........read.txt",false);
xhr.send(); 
console.log(xhr.responseText);
```

Comment: using your code I got this error: uncaught type error: cannot set property "innerHtml" of null

Comment: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user’s experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/ rpg_objects.js line 10500 > eval:8:2
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://....read.txt. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Answer (score 0):

Remove `false` in `xhr.open()` function.
Set `onreadystatechange`.
You will get what you want!

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET","http://...........read.txt");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
xhr.send();
```